# How to connect AZ Blob storage with App webhook using Event grid?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid, azure-webhooks

Hi im trying to do an exercise in Azure, i need that when a blob is created in my container, capture the event toward AZ Event grid(topic) using a suscription with a controller type webhook.

The suscription has been created, but **i dont know how or where register the event toward the event grid**.

[image]

The container "sample-items":
[image]

Comment: have a look at the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema What is your storage account kind?

Comment: Its standar container blob storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your storage account screen snippet didn't show an *Account kind* for Azure Event Grid integration, see my example:

[image]

Also, there is a Note in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema):

[image]

Selecting on **Events**, you can subscribe your interest on the storage account topic, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

Comment: I updated my storage account to v2. But i need create the event from storage account page or from event grid page?

Comment: Now, you should see an Events feature in this storage account, that means, the storage will emit the events to the Azure Event Grid. Select the Events and create the Subscription for that system storage topics.

Comment: Yes i did that, i created the suscription from storage account specifying the topic than i had previously created, but when i go to the topic, i dont see the suscription, only see it from storage account

Comment: I do recommend reading the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/create-view-manage-system-topics Also, after what you updated your storage account, you should delete its old system topic and create new one. Basically, you can create a subscription either on the storage account pane or on the system topic pane. You should see all subscriptions on both ones.